# Consultar estadísticas de APPs iOS y Android

Tags: android, ios, descarga

Necesito poder consultar estadísticas de APP's desarrolladas por mi, pero subidas a las Store con diferentes cuentas de desarrollador.

¿Existe alguna manera, o portal web, desde el cual poder consultar número de descargas por cada APP?

¿Conocéis alguna manera mejor de llevar el control de APPS sin tener que acceder con cada cuenta y a cada una de las plataformas?

Comment: ¿Te refieres poder controlar una aplicación de terceros desde un mismo panel de monitorización?

Comment: @Error404 creo que lo necesita es obtener TODOS los datos de estadisticas que te proporcionan las cuentas de desarrollador, pero sin acceder a estas cuentas

Comment: Exacto @sioesi, tengo acceso a todas las cuentas, pero no puedo ir accediendo a 20 cuentas diferentes (multiplícalo por 2 porque tenemos de ambas plataformas), necesito un panel en el que vea el resumen de estadísticas de todas, pero en un solo vistazo.

Comment: @sioesi Sí, eso lo había entendido. En mi caso yo necesito también para cuentas a las que no tendría acceso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297936/is-it-possible-to-track-downloads-on-android-and-ios-applications-at-the-same-ti. Por eso he especificado, por si el OP no lo había especificado.

Comment: Esta pregunta no se ajusta bien a los temas pertinentes al sitio. No es una pregunta sobre programación ni sobre una herramienta usada para desarrollo, y además se basa en opiniones.

Comment: Hola diego, no lo tomes a mal, pero la pregunta no entra en la tematica del sitio, sin embargo. **Te recomiendo que uses** [Distimo](http://www.distimo.com/) y puedes crear una cuenta maestra y agregar todas tus cuentas de desarrollador y ya tienes un dashboard con todos los datos en un solo sitio